# How to have the same behaviour with return than print?

Tags: python, function, loops, printing, return

I understand that "return" stops when it is "satisfied" while print executes the whole function. That said, I can never get the same behaviour with a return. And why do beginners learn with print if it doesn't work afterwards ?

If i write :

```py
for i in range(1, 4):
    print(i)
```

I get :
1
2
3
.
But if i write :

```py
def function():
    for i in range(1, 4):
        return i

print(function())
```

I get :
1

How to have the same behaviour ? Usually i want to loop in my function, i don't want the first value.

#Edit : i tried to create a list with return, still not working fine :

```py
keys = []
values = []
def asking():
    
    for i in range(1, 21):
        keys.append(i)
    #return keys #works fine here, keys is 1 to 21
    values = ["_"]
    vide2 = dict(zip(keys, values))
    return vide2

print(asking())
```

I got : {1: '_'}

Comment: `return` and `print` do completely different things, additionally there is `yield`.

Comment: `print(function())` prints whatever the function returns. You might want to add `print(i)` instead of `return i` to print the value on every loop iteration on every function call

Comment: `zip` stops whenever the smallest sequence is exhausted.  Since your smallest sequence is a list with a single string, you only get one output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a data structure inside the function and return it, it's the only way to return more than a value.

```
def function():
    my_list = []
    for i in range(1, 21):
        my_list.append(i)
    return my_list
```

Note that the data structure (a simple list) is returned after the end of the for loop, this way it contains all your values.

append(i) is a built-in method that automatically puts the element i at the end of the list.

To print with no parenthesis nor commas:

```
the_list = function()
for elem in the_list:
    print(elem, end=" ")
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Basically, you are just reading the first element, printing it, reading the second one, printing it, and so on...

Comment: Thanks, it's clear here but then i have to use a list !

Comment: Yes, and you'd better get used to it, you'll use this (and other data structures) a lot. Note that generators (what you get when using `yield` inside a function) are a different, more advanced and complicated topic, so you should use lists for a start if you're a beginner.

Comment: As you can see in the edit, i tried but it's not working as expected

Comment: You aren't following my code, you are trying to create a dictionary with only one value.
Please stick to my code until you have fully understood it (lists are the simplest data structures)

Comment: If you want to print all the values without parenthesis and commas, check the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `yield` to create a generator:

```
def function():
    for i in range(1, 21):
        yield i


print(*function(), sep=' ')
```

Out:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i did not know the command "yield", pretty useful i will try to use